# Having trouble with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to get results for multiple criteria, but having trouble when I try to combine my two queries into one. I am looking to get the averages for the Miami Heat's win for the following categories + the averages of the New York Knicks losses for the following categories and combine them into one average.

So this is my query for the Heat which retrieves exactly what i want

```
SELECT  box_score.team_name, ROUND(AVG(eFG),3) eFG,
    ROUND(AVG(OPP_eFG),3) OPP_eFG,
    ROUND(AVG(TOV_PCT),3) TOV_PCT,
    ROUND(AVG(OPP_TOV_PCT),3) OPP_TOV_PCT,
    ROUND(AVG(ORB_PCT),3) ORB_PCT,
    ROUND(AVG(DRB_PCT),3) DRB_PCT,
    ROUND(AVG(FTA_RATE),3) FTA_RATE,
    ROUND(AVG(OPP_FTA_RATE),3) OPP_FTA_RATE
 FROM box_score
 WHERE team_name = "Miami Heat" AND WIN_LOSS = "W" AND game_date < "2019-03-07"
```

I also did the losses for the knicks which also resulted in what i wanted

```
WHERE team_name = "New York Knicks" AND WIN_LOSS = "L" AND game_date < "2019-03-07"
```

everything else was the same before that line...my problem is trying to combine the two into one query where I get the averages in the Heat's wins and the average in knick's losses. I'm thinking the issue is in the where clause but i can't figure it out, I can only get null results... all of this information is from the same table and I can get team information from an id number or by name... I am using SQLite if that changes anything

This is the result of running the query which is what i'm looking for one row of data with the average... however I would like the average of these numbers in both Heat wins and Knicks losses combined into one row this query only displays the averages averages in Heat wins.

Averages in Heat Wins

```
eFG    OPP_eFG   TOV_PCT OPP_TOV_PCT ORB_PCT DRB_PCT  FTA_RATE  OPP_FTA_RATE
0.603    0.505    0.14     0.126     0.28       0.77      0.235      0.141
```

These are the averages in knicks losses

```
eFG    OPP_eFG TOV_PCT OPP_TOV_PCT ORB_PCT DRB_PCT  FTA_RATE   OPP_FTA_RATE       
0.568   0.602    0.146    0.136       0.225  0.787    0.222      0.235
```

I want to get the two combined into 1 average for each category

Comment: Share sample data, result you get and expected result

Comment: *combined into one row* so 1 row with 2 team names and how many columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT bs.team_name, ROUND(AVG(eFG),3) eFG,
       ROUND(AVG(OPP_eFG),3) OPP_eFG,
       ROUND(AVG(TOV_PCT),3) TOV_PCT,
       ROUND(AVG(OPP_TOV_PCT),3) OPP_TOV_PCT,
       ROUND(AVG(ORB_PCT),3) ORB_PCT,
       ROUND(AVG(DRB_PCT),3) DRB_PCT,
       ROUND(AVG(FTA_RATE),3) FTA_RATE,
       ROUND(AVG(OPP_FTA_RATE),3) OPP_FTA_RATE
FROM box_score bs
WHERE game_date < '2019-03-07' and
      ( (team_name = 'Miami Heat' AND WIN_LOSS = 'W') OR
        (team_name = 'New York Knicks' AND WIN_LOSS = 'L') 
      )
GROUP BY bs.team_name;
```

I might also suggest that you include `WIN_LOSS` in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`, so it is also in the result set.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, just remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(eFG),3) eFG,
       ROUND(AVG(OPP_eFG),3) OPP_eFG,
       ROUND(AVG(TOV_PCT),3) TOV_PCT,
       ROUND(AVG(OPP_TOV_PCT),3) OPP_TOV_PCT,
       ROUND(AVG(ORB_PCT),3) ORB_PCT,
       ROUND(AVG(DRB_PCT),3) DRB_PCT,
       ROUND(AVG(FTA_RATE),3) FTA_RATE,
       ROUND(AVG(OPP_FTA_RATE),3) OPP_FTA_RATE
FROM box_score bs
WHERE game_date < '2019-03-07' and
      ( (team_name = 'Miami Heat' AND WIN_LOSS = 'W') OR
        (team_name = 'New York Knicks' AND WIN_LOSS = 'L') 
      );
```

Comment: @GDolan . . . Your question is rather ambiguous.  I still read it and think that you want two rows in one query.

Comment: @GDolan . . . The revised version doesn't do what you want?

Comment: @GDolan . . . I can only say that this averages all rows that match.  Are you sure the query returns the information about the Knicks if you remove the filtering for the Heat?

Comment: I just realized I made a typo somehow in the team name so i fixed it and the query works exactly the way i want now... thank you